# Hide if one radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button, onchange

I'm trying to build a form that has a radio buttons with two values in the top `1` and `2`. If the radio button with the value of `1` is checked, I want one input box with the `id` = `facebook` to hide. On load, there's no radio button checked. This is my code:

```
$("input[name='accountType']").change(function(){

    var radio;
    radio = $("input[name='accountType']").val();

    if(radio === '1'){
        ("#facebook").hide();
    }

});
```

This is my HTML

```
<input type="text" name="facebook" id="facebook" value="" class="form-control">


<input type="radio" name="accountType" id="accountType-1" value="1" class="icheck" >
<input type="radio" name="accountType" id="accountType-2" value="2" class="icheck" >
```

I'm sure its obvious but I'm just starting to work with jQuery and I've tried different answers here but they don't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: sorry about that. That was part of the jquery plugin I use to style them. I removed it.

Comment: make sure to check for console errors.  For example, `("#facebook").hide();` will show an error because it needs a `$` before it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more simple:

```
$('input[name=accountType]').change(function(){
  $('#facebook').toggle(this.value !== '1');
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/74N3g/). First, `change` event is fired on the radio button that's checked, so there's no need to look for it with the full selector again - `this` would refer to the corresponding element, and `this.value` will give you its value.

Second, there's a convenient `.toggle` jQuery method that can be used to show or hide the element depending on some condition (show if it's truthy, hide if falsy). In this case, you need to hide the element if `this.value` *is* equal to '1', that's why I reverse the check (with `!==`).

As a sidenote, I've removed the quotation marks around 'accountType' - these are not required if attribute value (in attribute selector) is a valid JS identifier.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason that doesn't work. I updated the question and added my html. Maybe something I'm overlooking.

Comment: @raygo Sigh. This is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Zwh5/) based on the _current_ version of the code shown. I do understand that it's hard to prepare the question - but please don't omit the _key_ parts of the problem.

Comment: I guess there's something else wrong with my code. I copied pasted this and still doesn't work. I'm going to put in a jsfiddle the actual code from the dev tool.

Comment: @raygo Sure, no problem. Just wanted to illustrate the approach in general with these two points: 1) work with `this` in `change` handler, it will contain the DOM element checked; 2) use `.toggle()` to change the element's visibility based on some condition.

Comment: It's a problem with my plugin. icheck. Will have to add another question

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do

```js
$('input[name=accountType]').change(function(){
if($('#accountType-1').is(':checked')) { $('#facebook').css('display', "none"); }

 });
```